# GNAT GPS: Add a custom command

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps

I would like to know if it is possible to add a custom command to the GNAT Programming Studio (GPS)?

If the custom command is invoked (by a button in the menu bar or a keyboard shortcut) an external Python script should be called with the full/absolute path to the file that is opened and selected in the editor.

Comment: Suggest you run GPS and go to the menu Help > GPS > Python extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick-and-dirty script that might give some direction. I tested it on Linux, but it should also work on Windows. Change the action near the end to invoke the script you like. To actually use it, you must put it in the (hidden) `.gps/plug-ins` directory which can be found in your home directory. The actual action can be invoked from the context menu in the source code window.

**run_my_script.py**

```py
"""Run Python Script

This plug-in executes a python script.
"""

###########################################################################
# No user customization below this line
###########################################################################

import os, sys
import GPS
from gps_utils import interactive

def __contextualMenuFilter(context):

    # Check if the context is generated by the source editor
    if not (context.module_name == "Source_Editor"):
        return False

    # If all OK, show the menu item in the context menu.
    return True

def __contextualMenuLabel(context):

    # Get current buffer
    name = context.file().name()
    basename = os.path.basename(name)

    # Name of the menu item.
    return "Run Python script for <b>{}</b>".format(basename)

@interactive(
    name       ="Run Python script",
    contextual = __contextualMenuLabel,
    filter     = __contextualMenuFilter)
def on_activate():

    # If modified, then save before proceeding.
    eb = GPS.EditorBuffer.get()
    if eb.is_modified:
        eb.save()

    # Run the action (defined below).
    GPS.execute_action("my_script")

GPS.parse_xml ("""
   <action name="my_script">
     <external output="Output of my_script">python3 /home/deedee/my_script.py %F</external>
   </action>""")
```

**my_script.py** (some test script)

```py
import sys

print ("Running script {0} for {1}".format(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1]));
```

**output** (shown in GPS on a new tab named "Output of my_script")

```
python3 /home/deedee/my_script.py /home/deedee/example/src/main.adb
Running script /home/deedee/my_script.py for /home/deedee/example/src/main.adb
```

Some relevant info from the GNAT Studio (formerly GPS) documentation:

- [15.5.2. Defining Actions](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/extending.html#defining-actions)
- [15.5.3. Macro arguments](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/extending.html#macro-arguments)
- [15.8.7.3. Redirecting the output of spawned processes](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/extending.html#redirecting-the-output-of-spawned-processes)
- [17. Scripting API reference for GPS](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/GPS.html#module-GPS)

Comment: Thanks for your nice example script. If my Python script modifies the referenced file on the disk, GPS asks me if I am interested in reloading the file. Could this behaviour be suppressed by the Python plugin script? I don't want to disable this reload question globally.

Comment: You might want to try adding a callback to the appropriate hook (e.g. `file_changed_detected` as described the [GNAT Studio documentation](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gps/html/gps_ug/GPS.html#GPS.Predefined_Hooks.file_changed_detected)).