# Callling a python script from GNAT, configured for ada

Tags: python, ada, gnat

Is there anyway possible to call a python script from gnat project which is configured for ada.
I've seen gnat extensible is available where we can add a call in .gpr (the project file for GNAT ada) for python script. But how this can be done is point of Interest. If anybody has done this earlier, please share some idea about it how to do. I've seen [Adding custom command which uses python script with gnat and ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345798/gnat-gps-add-a-custom-command) but no idea how gpr file was configured according to it.
Thank in Advance.

---

**UPDATE**

I found that script created, in Plug-in section of Preferences, after following the procedure described in Link above.
But still unaware of **How to Execute it?**

Comment: what have you tried so far please and where does it fail ?

Comment: GNATcoll has python/python3 bindings https://github.com/AdaCore/gnatcoll-bindings

Comment: @D.L, I've followed the exact way as mentioned in link of my query, I put that script in the plug-in folder but failed, as I didn't found that plug-in anywhere in the IDE. After which the question raised how to call it. or where that plug-in is supposed to be called/added.

Comment: @JesperQuorning That link is a source how to bind the python with gprbuild. But my IDE is already bind with python and python3.

Comment: Well, what is this source code you’re not supposed to change? Why/how doesn’t it do what you want it to?

Comment: In the example cited, the project's `.gpr` file was not modified; the `run_my_script.py` file was added to the  `.gps/plug-ins` directory.

Comment: @trashgod Yeah, I think that's correct, I found my script in the plug-in section. But now how to make it execute, is main task. Like I've added prints in the python script, so if that executes in GNAT, I'll get the prints in Message/Console section.

Comment: @SimonWright I'm on a Intermediate level currently in my company, so modifying source code for a accessory task is not permitted. Instead of that, I can modify the tool like, I can add a button in GNAT Interface, which will react on Click-events as per the requirement.

Comment: I could have this wrong, but it seems as though you want to call a Python script from your Ada program, without changing your Ada program, by putting a Python script in your IDE (GPS). This is not possible. The Python scripting in GPS provides a way to customise GPS, and that is all.